# Lemmatize using Textblob in python

Tags: python, lemmatization, textblob

I have written code for lemmatize  sentence in Python using text blob but I am not getting the expected result:

```
def get_lemmatize_text(transcript):
    transcript = transcript.strip()
    blob = TextBlob(transcript)
    for word in blob:
        expected_str = Word(word)
        expected_str = expected_str.lemmatize()
    return expected_str
print(get_lemmatize_text("he had not received the four letters we d sent him as he had been travelling for the whole of august and hadn t received any call or text from us . he has just arrived today and has called us straight away . he has also just of his account when he had asked for it to be cancelled before it switched from the first additions datestr . he says he received contact from us that we were looking into this but doesnot have that to hand"))
```

I get following as output: 
`d`

What has gone wrong? Can anyone help me or correct me?

Comment: try this,
TextBlob(transcript).split()
and append result of expected_str in list each time

Comment: make expected_str list instead of variable so that it will return list of words rather than jet a word

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterating the sentence as character wise `.split()` will take care of it. then you are not preserving your result that's why you are getting the result of last iteration `list` append will take care of it. If you solve this two problems your code will work fine :)
try this,

```
   blob = TextBlob(transcript).split()
   result=[]
   for word in blob:
        expected_str = Word(word)
        expected_str = expected_str.lemmatize()
        result.append(expected_str)
   return result #or try this return ' '.join(result)
```